# Scability of Ruby-PHP-Python on Cassandra/Hadoop on 500M+ users

Tags: php, python, ruby-on-rails, scalability, cassandra

Which one of Ruby-PHP-Python is best suited for Cassandra/Hadoop on 500M+ users?  I know language itself is not a big concern but I like to know base on proven success, infrastructure and available utilities around those frameworks! thanks so much.

Comment: By "500M+ users", do you really mean 500 million?  That would be quite impressive :)

Comment: LOL. You just described facebook. Good show, troll.

Comment: This is a pointless question. The language doesn't matter at all, any of the 3 would be suitable with smart enough developers and enough hardware.

Comment: Facebook uses compiled PHP. But even they didn't start out by planning for 500M users. They started with normal PHP and wrote the compiler themselves when they found they needed it.

Comment: Perhaps he's from Italy? M=Mille=1000. Be nice :)

Comment: Everbody wants to be the next facebook

Answer (score 0):

Because Cassandra is written in Java, a client also in Java would likely have the best stability and maturity for your application.

As far as choosing between those 3 dynamic languages, I'd say whatever you're most comfortable with is best.  I don't know of any significant differences between client libraries in those languages.